# measuring TX retransmission amount per interface

Tags: linux, network-programming, libpcap

i'm trying to get the TX re-transmission amount for a specific network interface on a Linux 2.6.33.3 kernel.
is there any Linux raw data i can use in order to get/calculate this kind of information?
i've tried `netstat`, but i couldn't find a way to get the retransmissions value for a specific interface.
with no other "quick" choice, what would it require from me in order to build a small app especially for that? listen to all outgoing packets using any capturing library and count.. what? duplicate packets? by some kind of a packet id?
i'm not a network pro.. am i suppose to find troubles in this kind of mission? (btw, i'll probably try to do it with python. any reason why not to?)

Comment: Did you find the solution to find the retransmitted packets per interface..Actually i am also facing the same issue....

Answer (score 1):

You can check how your interface is configured with the following commands:

```
mii-tool eth0
ethtool eth0
mii-diag eth0
```

Not all of them are installed by default in any Linux system, but they are definitely in the distributive and installable.

When you want to measure, how fast is your interface really, you can use `dd` + `netcat`:

```
host1$ cat /dev/zero | nc -l -p 3000
host2$ nc host1 3000 | dd of=/dev/null
^C
```

`dd` will write you with which speed was the retransmission between `host1` and `host2`.

Comment: well, that's a good tip i'll use for speed-test, but here i'm trying to get the re-transmission amount of an already transmitting interface. I've tried the suggested tools but couldn't found something useful. did i missed it?

Comment: You mean how many packets were retransmitted? This information must be in `ifconfig` output

Comment: i hardly believe that ifconfig display this data, since it's not in the "interface" scope, but a protocol one. for 'ifconfig' everything i usual - no error, no drops. i'm trying to measure the total TCP re-transmissions for an interface (caused by non-acked packets and not by line errors).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. You can find the number of tcp-retransmits in `/proc/net/snmp` (`RetransSegs` field) but it is for the wole system, for all its interfaces. I'm not sure that it is possible to find this information for each interface separately.

Comment: Another idea: you can write `pcap`-file for the interface and then analyze it and ind how many packets were retransmitted. To make this analysis you can try to use scapy (http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), or you can convert pcap file to xml and then analyze it wit your favorite language

Answer (score 0):

If you want per interface, try ifconfig eth0, you probably have what you want there. Just parse it through python.

Comment: ifconfig indeed has some information about an interface, but i couldn't find any reliable information for measuring re-transmission. it contains details about errors, drops and so on, but not re-trans. the only way i can use ifconfig is to decrease my sent app-data length from the total sent bytes. but it's highly unreliable.